# WF Service on Azure, need to change/increase maxStringContentLength on basicHttpBinding

Tags: azure, workflow

Somewhat of a newbie with this, but I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out..  I have a WF Service1.xamlx in an Azure WebRole, with a web.config ServiceModel section that includes:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="~/Service1.xamlx" service="Service1.xamlx" factory="System.ServiceModel.Activities.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

In my client app, when I add the service reference to Service1.xaml, this is what I get for the binding (all default settings for the basicHttpBinding):

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```

I need to increase the maxStringContentLength="8192" value in the binding. How do I do that??

Thanks for looking at this and any help you can provide.